# dataframe to list of dataframes based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:

```
df=
         columnDate    column_key      v1   v2 ... vN
0         01/01/2000       'a'         1    3
1         01/01/2000       'b'         2    4
2         02/01/2000       'a'         3    5
3         02/01/2000       'b'         4    6
...
```

I would like to split this dataframe into a dictionary of dataframes, one for each of the original `v1..vN` columns, and to have the possible values in `columnDate`    as new columns and values of `columns_key` as index.

For this example, the desired output is:

```
output['v1']=
      01/01/2000    02/01/2000    
'a'    1               3      
'b'    2               4       

output['v2']=
      01/01/2000    02/01/2000    
'a'    3               5      
'b'    4               6
```

N.B: the missing values in `df` should be filled with np.nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['column_key','columnDate']).unstack()
print (df1)
                   v1                    v2           
columnDate 01/01/2000 02/01/2000 01/01/2000 02/01/2000
column_key                                            
'a'                 1          3          3          5
'b'                 2          4          4          6
```

Then in `dict comprehension` select by first level of `MultiIndex` by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html):

```
output = {x:df1.xs(x, axis=1) for x in df1.columns.levels[0]}
print (output)
{'v1': columnDate  01/01/2000  02/01/2000
column_key                        
'a'                  1           3
'b'                  2           4, 'v2': columnDate  01/01/2000  02/01/2000
column_key                        
'a'                  3           5
'b'                  4           6}
```

---

```
print (output['v1'])
columnDate  01/01/2000  02/01/2000
column_key                        
'a'                  1           3
'b'                  2           4

print (output['v2'])
columnDate  01/01/2000  02/01/2000
column_key                        
'a'                  3           5
'b'                  4           6
```